# carat and New line issues using NHAPI tool in .NET

Tags: hl7

I'm using `NHapi v22` tool for sending HL7 messages. Issue is I'm not able to create component separator(^) and new line. Please tell me how to code for it in C#.

Following is the code:

```
MSH|^~\&|xyz|xyz|FLOW|FLOW|201601201525||ADT\S\A04|201601201525123456789|P|2.3|||NE|NE
```

I need to get like this- `ADT^A04`

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue here is that \S\ is an escape character for ^ (component separator). Your message should contain an actual component separator with the actual ^ in it, not the escape character.

"ADT" should appear in MSH-9-1 and "A04" should appear in MSH-9-2 as opposed to how I suspect you are doing it with "ADT^A01" in MSH-9.

Does this help? Please feel free to contact me directly if you need more specialized advice.

edit: I don't normally use NHapi but I suspect you may need to do something along this line:

```
terser.set("/MSH-9-1", "ADT");
terser.set("/MSH-9-2", "A01");
```

as opposed to something you might be doing

```
terser.set("/MSH-9", "ADT^A01");
```